# Could someone explain to me how scanf works with multiple input sessions with C?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

Before anyone rants I know the coding is ugly and might be tedious to get through with all of the variables, but there just for the for loops so don't let those bother you. The problem is, I must take a user's input ie: account number and account pin and check whether they type the correct pin and account number according to what the random account number and random pin number generate. My functions for checking the account number and account pin work, no problem there. I have some DEBUG statements in there to try and catch where the problem is happening. I've noticed the problem occurring in the while loop where if the user enters either the account number or the pin number incorrectly on the first try, it loops back and asks again, however when it asks the user again for the info for the second try, the array's with the new info from the user are not storing the new info, instead there still passing the old info from the original attempt. Is there something I'm not aware of with `scanf` that's making it not scan in the new info over the old or does it not even work like that?

Sample Input and Output:

```
Account Number: 67561

PIN: 2531

Please Enter account Number: 67562

Please Enter account PIN: 2531

Account Number DEBUG: 67562Account PIN DEBUG: 2531

ACCNT2

PIN1

Please Enter account Number: 67561

Please Enter account PIN: 2531

Account Number DEBUG2: 67562Account PIN DEBUG2: 2531

DEBUG2 2DEBUG3 1Please Enter account Number:
```

As you can see in the second attempt in the Debug2 statement it still took the original input instead of taking the new one I assigned it. Any ideas as to what's wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int check_login(int rand_account[], int account[]);
int check_login_pin(int rand_pin[], int pin[]);

int main(void) {

    char account_nmb[5],account_pin[4];
    int i,e,x,y,a,b,number=1,attempts=1,rand_pin[4], rand_account_number[5], account_nmb_int[5],account_pin_int[4];
    int d,f,account_number,account_pn,g,h,j,k;
    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    //generate array of rand account numbers and pin numbers
    for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        rand_account_number[x]=rand()%9;
    }
    for(y=0;y<5;y++){
        rand_pin[y]=rand()%9;
    }

    //print array of rand account numbers and pin numbers
    printf("Account Number: ");
    for(a=0;a<5;a++){
        printf("%d",rand_account_number[a]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("PIN: ");
    for(b=0;b<4;b++){
        printf("%d",rand_pin[b]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //Check User's input for match with random account number and pin
    while(attempts!=3){
        //Take user's input
        printf("Please Enter account Number: ");
        scanf("%s", account_nmb);
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            account_nmb_int[i] = account_nmb[i] - '0';
        }
        printf("Please Enter account PIN: ");
        scanf("%s", account_pin);
        for (e = 0; e < 4; e++ ) {
            account_pin_int[e] = account_pin[e] - '0';
        }

        //DEBUG
        printf("Account Number DEBUG: ");
        for(d=0;d<5;d++){
            printf("%d",account_nmb_int[d]);
        }
        printf("Account PIN DEBUG: ");
        for(f=0;f<4;f++){
            printf("%d",account_pin_int[f]);
        }


        account_number=check_login(rand_account_number, account_nmb_int);
        account_pn=check_login_pin(rand_pin,account_pin_int);

        //DEBUG
        printf("\nACCNT%d",account_number);
        printf("\nPIN%d\n",account_pn);

        if(account_number==2||account_pn==2){
            printf("Please Enter account Number: ");
            scanf("%s", account_nmb);
            for (g = 0; g < 4; g++ ) {
                account_nmb_int[g] = account_nmb[g] - '0';
            }
            printf("Please Enter account PIN: ");
            scanf("%s", account_pin);
            for (h = 0; h < 4; h++ ) {
                account_pin_int[h] = account_pin[h] - '0';
            }

            //DEBUG
            printf("Account Number DEBUG2: ");
            for(d=0;d<5;d++){
                printf("%d",account_nmb_int[d]);
            }
            printf("Account PIN DEBUG2: ");
            for(f=0;f<4;f++){
                printf("%d",account_pin_int[f]);
            }
            printf("\n");

            account_number=check_login(rand_account_number, account_nmb_int);
            account_pn=check_login_pin(rand_pin,account_pin_int);
            //DEBUG
            printf("DEBUG2 %d",account_number);
            printf("DEBUG3 %d",account_pn);
            attempts++;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nCONGRATS\n");
            attempts=3;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int check_login(int rand_account[], int account[]){
    int index,number;

    //check user account number and pin number with random generation
    for(index=0;index<5;index++){
        if(account[index]==rand_account[index]){
            number=1;
        }
        else{
            number = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
    return number;
}

int check_login_pin(int rand_pin[], int pin[]){
    int index, number;
    for(index=0;index<4;index++){
        if(pin[index]==rand_pin[index]){
            number=1;
        }
        else{
            number = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
    return number;

}
```

Comment: You've only allocated space for 5 characters for the account number, but you want to treat it as a string, so you need to allow for a terminating null.  And all hell breaks loose when you do type a 5 digit number to `scanf()` and it null terminates the input in the 6th place, which isn't part of the variable you wanted it to be saved in.  You also assume, without checking, that the user entered digits.  You also generate 5 digits for the PIN; that's not good since you only allocated space for 4 digits.

Comment: It works okay for me.  Though I typed only 4 digits for both account and PIN, and I compiled it on a 64-bit machine, so there should be 8 bytes (chars) reserved for each char array.

Comment: Except on RAM-restricted embedded platforms, you should stop counting stuff.  Every time you find yourself declaring a char buffer type smaller than [256], you should rethink it, several times.

Comment: `for (g = 0; g < 4; g++ )` should be `for (g = 0; g < 5; g++ )`. That is, the `scanf` may be working but the last char is not being converted to int. If that is not the problem, please show the exact input you are testing with.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i fixed the typo on the random_pin, the program begins to recognize the new input after the second iteration though the loop. So on the third attempt at inputing the numbers it will recognize the new input, however on the second attempt it completely overlooks the new input. It's assumed the user will only be able to input int's.

Comment: @kaylum the exact input is shown already in the Sample input output.

Comment: @Senglish I had a cached version before you added the sample input. But yes, it does confirm what I said. It's not using old input from `scanf`. It's only the last digit of the account which is not being converted to int. Try a completely different number for the second attempt account number and you will see all the digits are correct except the last.

Comment: @kaylum the fix for the g variable in the for loop fixed the incorrect input process!! However, the if statement is not recognizing that the account_number and account_pn have now changed to 1. So it's not breaking out of the loop on the second try...

Comment: When you scan `2531` into the PIN storage, you write beyond the end of the array that you've allocated. That is undefined behaviour — anything that happens after that is at the whim of the system; anything can happen and it is correct. You **cannot** afford a buffer overflow. Likewise with the 5 characters allocated for the account number and 5-digits entered. You **MUST** remember to allocate enough space for terminating nulls. You don't constrain the lengths of the inputs, either.  If you type extra digits, or non-digits, all hell breaks loose. I agree with Martin James — use bigger buffers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok, so extend the max size of the arrays for the char input's to 6 and 5 then to allow for the null terminating character /0 that usually follows in a scanf input?

Comment: That's the bare minimum change (and it is `'\0'` with a backslash, not a forward slash).  And it isn't safe — it isn't remotely safe.  But it is the minimum necessary change to start having a chance of being faintly correct.

Comment: @Senglish Your `if` is not until after the **third** `scanf` attempt. That is, the first set of `scanf` inside the loop are unconditional. But really, repeating the same code over multiple times is really not ideal (error prone, hard to maintain). You should only have a single set of `scanf` calls and the loop should stop immediately when the input is as expected.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks a bunch! I solved the problem, in the if statement I just removed the set of statements with input and had it just attempts++ and rerun the loop. Works great! Thanks everyone for the tips on memory and array allocation! My class just got into data structures and malloc so everything you guys said I'll keep in mind for my next assignments! Thanks everyone!

Comment: When I copy the code verbatim (into a file `bungycord.c`) and attempt to compile it, I get: `bungycord.c:22:20: error: iteration 4u invokes undefined behavior [-Werror=aggressive-loop-optimizations] rand_pin[y]=rand()%9;`
(counting from 0, of course) and
`bungycord.c:21:5: note: containing loop for(y=0;y<5;y++){`
`cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`. I'm using GCC 5.2.0 (`gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror`). I also get errors from the 3 unused variables you define. You can't afford not to compile with similarly stringent options — they tell you when you're coding it wrong!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand that and I removed the extra variables but what your saying I'm not sure pertains to what I'm being asked to do. I'm using C99 and im just simply being asked to create a random account number and pin, ask the user to input those (so literally copy and paste what the random generator creates) and they have 3 attempts to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the problem was first fixing the array size of both account number and pin to include the '\0' null terminating character as pointed out by @Jonathan Leffler. Secondly the other problem was having the if statement run a second input and print phase when rather it should just push the while loop to it's second iteration allowing for the new input to come through as pointed out by @kaylum. Thanks everyone for the help and advice with array and data storage!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int check_login(int rand_account[], int account[]);
int check_login_pin(int rand_pin[], int pin[]);

int main(void) {

    char account_nmb[6],account_pin[5];
    int i,e,x,y,a,b,attempts=0,rand_pin[5], rand_account_number[6], account_nmb_int[6],account_pin_int[5];
    int d,f,account_number,account_pn;
    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    //generate array of rand account numbers and pin numbers
    for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        rand_account_number[x]=rand()%9;
    }
    for(y=0;y<4;y++){
        rand_pin[y]=rand()%9;
    }

    //print array of rand account numbers and pin numbers
    printf("Account Number: ");
    for(a=0;a<5;a++){
        printf("%d",rand_account_number[a]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("PIN: ");
    for(b=0;b<4;b++){
        printf("%d",rand_pin[b]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    //Check User's input for match with random account number and pin
    while(attempts!=3){
        //Take user's input
        printf("Please Enter account Number: ");
        scanf(" %s", account_nmb);
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            account_nmb_int[i] = account_nmb[i] - '0';
        }
        printf("Please Enter account PIN: ");
        scanf(" %s", account_pin);
        for (e = 0; e < 4; e++ ) {
            account_pin_int[e] = account_pin[e] - '0';
        }

        //DEBUG
        printf("Account Number DEBUG: ");
        for(d=0;d<5;d++){
            printf("%d",account_nmb_int[d]);
        }
        printf("Account PIN DEBUG: ");
        for(f=0;f<4;f++){
            printf("%d",account_pin_int[f]);
        }


        account_number=check_login(rand_account_number, account_nmb_int);
        account_pn=check_login_pin(rand_pin,account_pin_int);

        //DEBUG
        printf("\nACCNT%d",account_number);
        printf("\nPIN%d\n",account_pn);

        if(account_number==2||account_pn==2){
            attempts++;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nCONGRATS\n");
            attempts=3;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int check_login(int rand_account[], int account[]){
    int index,number=1;

    //check user account number and pin number with random generation
    for(index=0;index<5;index++){
        if(account[index]==rand_account[index]){
            number=1;
        }
        else{
            number = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
    return number;
}


int check_login_pin(int rand_pin[], int pin[]){
    int index, number=1;
    for(index=0;index<4;index++){
        if(pin[index]==rand_pin[index]){
            number=1;
        }
        else{
            number = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
    return number;

}
```